# Why does this SQL query that appears to be missing a space work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A friend of mine discovered this and I tested it and confirmed in SQL Server Management Studio.  If you find a column that is an `INT`, you can query:

```
select * 
from table 
where foo = 1AND 1=1; /* works no problem */
```

Note that there's no space between the 1 and the `AND`. We're wondering why this isn't an issue for SQL. Is this a known SQL behavior?

Comment: Identifiers can't start with a number. And numbers can't contain an 'A'. So the lexer is able to tell the two tokens apart.

Comment: The parser is able to tell when the number ends and the keyword begins

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Transact-SQL Reference: Data Types: Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) page lists the valid syntaxes for constants. `1` is a valid constant. `1A` is not a start of any possible valid constant, so the parser stops reading there.

Note that it doesn't work like that with all letters though: `E` can appear in a number. Because of that, `select 1except select 1` is still valid but not what you might expect. This is parsed as `select 1e as xcept` where the optional keyword `as` has been omitted, followed by an additional statement `select 1`. It is completely different from `select 1 except select 1`.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually just trying to get it to complain about a syntax error, and quite confused at first when I got results. :)

Comment: Based on the frequency at which I encounter errors when writing SQL I'm surprised it works. Your example makes it even worse to me, I think they should yell at you when you do either of these things.

Answer (score 2):

No different from `1=1` or `1+1`. See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/829):

```
select case when 'a'in('a','b')then'a'else'b'end;
```

Same result in MySQL btw.